# Get one css file from webpack multiple entry points

Tags: webpack, extract-text-plugin

I use webpack for my project. I have 2 entry points: the first one's for CSS files with CSS modules, the second - for global css files. Main.css isn't imported from any file in project so I made a special entry point for it.

```
const extractStylesCss = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');  

entry: {
    'main': ["./src/index.tsx"],
    'styles': "./src/main.css"
},
module: {
    loaders: [ 
        {
            test: /^.*\.css$/,
            exclude: [
                path.join(__dirname, 'src/main.css')
            ],

            loader: extractStylesCss.extract(
                "style",
                `css?modules&importLoaders=2&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]___${pjson.version}!typed-css-modules!postcss?pack=pure&sourceMap=inline`
            )
        },
        {
            test: /main\.css$/,
            loader: extractStylesCss.extract('style', 'css!postcss?pack=pure&sourceMap=inline')
        },
    ]
},
plugins: [
    extractStylesCss
],
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/docs"),
    filename: "[name].js"
}
```

I need only one output file - styles.css. I know that ExtractTextPlugin generates one bundle per entry point, but is there any possibility to get one file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had the right idea by adding it to the entry, unfortunately you created another bundle. Each property of the `entry` object creates a separate bundle, this is why you also get a `style.js` even though it only has the webpack bootstrap code in it and `extract-text-webpack-plugin` just overwrites the CSS file if you use the same output file for both.

What you really want is adding the `main.css` to the main bundle (it should conceptually be part of it, not in a separate bundle). The entries also accept an array with multiple entry points. With the following `entry` the CSS will automatically be combined:

```
entry: {
    main: ['./src/index.tsx', './src/main.css']
},
```